# Display a Floating UIView on Screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

is it Possible to display a UIView on iPad Screen without adding it to any other view?
When I tap and keep tapped anywhere on the screen view should appear on the tap location and as soon as i take finger up View should disappear...
**NOTE:** Tap gesture is added to a view holds full screen

Comment: You can show the view on tap and hide it when tap is release

Comment: how i can show view without adding it to other view?

Comment: take the view in your xib. Initially hide it and then you can show. Can you tell the reason why you dont want to add?

Comment: this is about knowing that is their a trick or not?

Comment: only thing is you can make a custom view and show and hide whenever u need it. I hope you got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying a floating UIView without adding to any subview is **obviously not Possible**. **IOS** system is designed in that way. You have a **Window and a root viewController** for each application. Every thing else is added to this **viewController**. to achieve something like **floating UIView** you have to add it to the main view controller as a subview to display and remove it when it is not necessery. Your main View would be the root **viewController's View** covering complete device screen. I am assuming You know how to add and remove a subview from a view.

Answer (score 1):

You can't display a view unless it's a subview of some other view. That's how the iOS system works - it's a hierarchy of views.
If you want you can add your view to UIWindow, which is the top-most view of your app.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easiest way to display a floating UIView on screen.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var remoteVideoView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleGesture(_:)))
        remoteVideoView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        remoteVideoView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
}
    
    
    @objc func handleGesture(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        // handling code
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
        let remoteVideoView = gesture.view!
        remoteVideoView.center = CGPoint(x: remoteVideoView.center.x + translation.x, y: remoteVideoView.center.y + translation.y )
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default add UIView and it should be hidden and when user touch any postion just set your UIView postion as per your finger position. And when touch removed just hide that UIView.

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!

Comment: adding the view to other view and display it is simple enough.....please read the question :)

Comment: If you have UIViewController then can present it.But you have UIView so you have to addSubview. By using this you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your view to something. No other way.

Make a transparent view that will hold your floating view. Add the floating view to it with an alpha of 0.0.

Then implement touchesBegan on the transparent view:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
    NSLog(@"touches began");
    myFloatingView.alpha = 1.0;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
    NSLog(@"touches began");
    myFloatingView.alpha = 0.0;
}
```

Of course you'll want to animate the alpha a bit for a really slick effect.

Comment: Please pardon the formatting. I'm sending this from my phone.